# Return xml node containing queried word in xml using edittext

Tags: java, android, xml

Is there anyway to parse and search an XML located in assets folder using edittext and then return the node containing the searched/queried word?

E.g. My XML file would look like this:

book.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
    <books>
         <chapter number="1">
         <verse number="1">Some texts are here. This text is gonna be long paragraph</verse>
         <verse number="2">Some texts are here. This text is gonna be long paragraph</verse>
         <verse number ="3">Some texts are here. This text is gonna be long paragraph</verse>
         <verse number="4">Some texts are here. This text is gonna be long paragraph</verse>
</chapter>        
</books>
```

What I want to do is, I have an XML file inside assets folder, which I want to parse and search within that XML file for a particular word/words using EditText. Whenever I type for a particular word in EditText, I want that word to be parsed in the XML and then return the whole node containing the word as a result. Will that be possible? Can anyone suggest me a way to do that without using database.

I hope I am making sense here.

I apologise if this question is a duplicate or similar type of questions have already been asked before, but I would be so grateful if anyone could tell me how. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, the XML lookup is not related to EditText. You need a quick lookup in the xml file. I suggest to use [XMLBeam](http://xmlbeam.org)
Here is a unit test that works, assuming that your books.xml is reachable by the class loader (just next to the TestNodeContains.java):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.xmlbeam.XBProjector;
import org.xmlbeam.annotation.XBDocURL;
import org.xmlbeam.annotation.XBRead;

public class TestNodeContains {

@XBDocURL("resource://book.xml")
public interface Books {

    @XBRead("//verse[contains(text(),'{0}')]")
    String lookup(String string);

}

@Test
public void testXpathContains() throws IOException {
    Books books = new XBProjector().io().fromURLAnnotation(Books.class);
    System.out.println(books.lookup("word"));

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will definitely look into XMLBeam, have to figure out first how to use it though.